# how to use a ZF2 view helper from within a custom view helper

Tags: zend-framework2, view-helpers

I want to create a custom view helper to reuse a standard set of page links in several view scripts, and I am having trouble getting the urls from routing.  The ZF2 url helper `url($name, $urlParams, $routeOptions, $reuseMatchedParams` generates urls from route parameters if it is coded in the view script itself.  However, if I place the same code in my custom helper, I get the message:

```
 Call to undefined method myCustomHelperPath::url()
```

I understand that there are controller plugins to get the url from the routing, but I’m trying to get the url in a view helper, not a controller.  In my case, I want to use a ZF2 view helper from within my custom view helper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use other view helpers inside a custom view helper like below:

```
$this->view->otherHelper();
```

Comment: Awesome.  Is that published in the ZF2 documentation?  I couldn't find it.

Comment: +1 `$this->view->plugin('viewhelpername')` also works